# Exact diagonalisation by Bogoliubov-Valatin Rotation in the 'real -particle' space

Tags: condensed-matter, many-body, second-quantization, ising-model

I have a question about the random ising model, where the model is no longer translationally invariant, and one has to resort to diagonalizing the full hamiltonian rather than solve for decoupled $2X2$ matrices in the $(k,-k)$ subspace.

To be precise, consider the Hamiltonian in terms of spinless fermions on site with open boundary conditions

[image]

I write a matrix that gives me the correct eigenvalues and other properties, but I do not know what to make of the eigenvectors.

If I have $N$ sites, I get $2N$ eigenvectors, each of length $2N$, how do I map them to the $\bf{u}$ and $\bf{v}$ given below, especially since all elements are real.

[image]

**EDIT - I think I now understand the above construction. My question is - If I want to calculate correlators like $<c^{\dagger}_{i}c_{j}>$ and $<c^{\dagger}_{i}c^{\dagger}_{j}>$, say in the ground state, what is my eigenvector(column vector)) i.e $\psi_{0}$**

Note : Images taken from http://www.statphys.sissa.it/statistical/tesi_phd/canovi.pdf

Please see this for reference as well, pages 51 - 54.

Comment: It seems to me you answer yourself your question.... Everything is explained in your image. Would you please be more clear if there is something in particular you do not understand with the construction ?

Comment: @FraSchelle - thanks for your reply. I have now edited the question. thanks.